# std::map::insert change in C++17

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, move, c++17

I see that the `insert` method of `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` is going to change from

```
template<class P> std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(P&& value); (C++11)
```

to

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(value_type&& value);  (C++17)
```

However, for these containers, `value_type` is `std::pair<A const, int>`. Two questions here:

1. Why this change? What is the upside?
2. How is this going to work to move a key on insertion? The C++11 version accepts anything (the constraint on `P` is `default_constructible<value_type, P&&>`), then `std::pair<A, int>` - which is most of the time the type of this argument as it is the one returned by `std::make_pair` - and can call the move constructor of `A`. But in the C++17 version, this argument is casted to `value_type`, where `A` is const, then non-movable. A has to be copied, if I am not overlooking something. Or does C++17 change anything on that side too?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like that feature was added by [LWG 2354](http://wg21.link/lwg2354).

Comment: It's not "from X to Y". It's an additional overload.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An additional non-template overload to `insert` was added in C++17.

Such an overload has the advantage that it permits `.insert( { {key}, {value, args} } )` syntax -- `{}` based construction.  `template` arguments cannot be passed `{}` based construction instructions without an explicit type.

Comment: Thanks ; indeed it is an additional overload that will allow to write this `{}` based construction, but it will still be treat as a `std::pair<Key const, Value>`, so I guess `key` in your example won't be moved but copied...? I am actually pretty sure the C++ guys thought about that and it will be moved, I just don't see *how* if it is const :)

Comment: @AntiClimacus It will call the constructors of `std::pair`, whatever they are.  If `std::pair<const Key, Value>` can be constructed by (say) `(Key&&, Value&&)` then the data could be moved-into the `insert`.  It could not, however, be moved-into the data in the tree, yes.